# Error while inserting data into Mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, insert

I am trying to insert data into Mysql table, but it is giving me an error as-

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Scoretab VALUES ('UX 345','22','0.8562675')' at line 1

This is the php-mysql snippet that im using :

```
if($value >= 0.70){         
  $mu_id = $ros['c_id'];
  $moc_id = $ram['t_id'];
  $query="INSERT INTO Scoretab VALUES ('$mu_id','$moc_id','$value')";

  $op1 = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());         
}
```

This is my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Scoretab` (
 `mu_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `moc_id` int(5) NOT NULL,
 `score` decimal(5,4) NOT NULL,
 UNIQUE KEY `mu_id` (`mu_id`)
)
```

Comment: and what is your table structure

Comment: what error it gave you.?

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Scoretab` (
  `mu_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `moc_id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `score` decimal(5,4) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `mu_id` (`mu_id`)
)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could potentially be a few problems with this query

```
$query="INSERT INTO Scoretab VALUES ('$mu_id','$moc_id','$value')";
```

- Does the number of columns match the fields your trying to insert? Have you tried using using specific column identifier `Scoretab (col,col,col) values (val, val, val)`
- Does any of your values contain an unescaped apostrophe? You might want to consider using [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/it/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) for `$mu_id` and [intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) for `$moc_id` maybe!
- `$value` is a float you don't need to ad apostrophes while inserting
- Are you sure you are connected to the same database you have this table in?

this could be a possible working solution (**edit**)

```
if ($value >= 0.70)
{
    $mu_id = mysql_real_escape_string($ros['c_id']);

    $moc_id = intval($ram['t_id']); 

    $query = "INSERT INTO `Scoretab` VALUES ('$mu_id', $moc_id, $value)";

    $op1 = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Yes i did use the Scoretab (col,col,col) values (val, val, val) format earlier, but the error persisted

Comment: I have also used  mysql_real_escape_string ,inorder to fix this issue i have removed  mysql_real_escape_string .

Comment: @shailbenq are you shure you are connected to the same database you have this table in?

Comment: Yes I am using require_once('db_connection.php'); in every php file where im doing DB operations

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29222/discussion-between-ivo-and-shailbenq)

Comment: finally got it with ` Scoretab `

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 $query="INSERT INTO Scoretab  (mu_id,moc_id,score) VALUES ('$mu_id','$moc_id','$value')";
```

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to be before the table name `Scoretab`. Did you check your syntax carefully?
Sometimes we don't see what's right in front of our eyes! :D
Just replicated the example and everything worked for me.

Comment: the query we see is most likely the query mysql is trying to parse... its there!

Comment: uhhh really odd! And if you try this... just because: `$query = "INSERT INTO Scoretab VALUES ('".$mu_id."', '".$moc_id."', '".$value."')";`